rviz2 unable to visulize msg from new gz-sim8 (gazebo harmonic) with ros-humble
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS 2 Humble and gz-sim8 (Gazebo Harmonic). I have gpu_lidar scan topic published from gazebo to ros topic using ros_gz_bridge. I can echo topic in the terminal. But when I try to visualize it in the rviz2 it shows following error constantly
 [INFO] [1722342149.025331805] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'tb3_1/lidar/gpu_lidar' at time 209.100 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'

I can see the robot model in rviz2 it is just the topics.
I have /clock topic directed from gazebo to ros.
I can see all the tf frames properly.
When I try ros2 topic delay /tb3_1/scan, It gives following results
average delay: 1722344806.669
    min: 1722344806.652s max: 1722344806.685s std dev: 0.00971s window: 9
average delay: 1722344806.684
    min: 1722344806.652s max: 1722344806.716s std dev: 0.01735s window: 19
average delay: 1722344806.698
    min: 1722344806.652s max: 1722344806.737s std dev: 0.02500s window: 28

It seem like sync issue but I don't know how to solve it after trying several things.
I tried to set use_sim_time to true and false for all the nodes. But it didn't work.
It is not just Lidar topic, the same error raised for Odometry as well.
Any idea what I might have missing?
Edit-1:
I tried to publish velocity to the robot with ros2 topic. It is moving in the gazebo but not in the rviz.
Note: I am not using the turtlebot3 pkg from github as it was not building properly for me. I have custom sdf files and launch files that works for ros-2 humble and gz-sim8. Although I am trying with tb3 but it seem like a general error rather associating with tb3.
